# How to fill the page with an image?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm basically a phone developer and have no knowledge about web programming. What I'm trying to do is loading an image with any width and height in a browser control of my mobile app with a fixed width (say 400px) and a growing height. that image should fill the browser control completely without any free spaces.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function () {
        var elem = document.getElementById('content');
        window.external.Notify(elem.scrollHeight + '');
    }
</script>
<div id="content">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0" />
    <img src="http://www.reactiongifs.com/r/iwsyih.gif" />
</div>
```

this, doesn't fill the page with image, and also its width is not 400. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you mean by browser control.
One way is to use and size a div element via CSS and set its background image via CSS property.

```
<div style=' /* more CSS */ background-image:url("foo.png");'></div>
```

For example see http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_background.asp

Answer (score 0):

you can some styling to your code :

```
<style>
image{
   position: absolute;
   height :100%
   width: 100%;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that by *browser control* you mean the window area. If so, you can set a `background-image` for the `<body>` tag and make it fill the whole area thanks to `background-size: cover`:

```css
body {
    background: url(http://www.reactiongifs.com/r/iwsyih.gif) no-repeat center center fixed;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;

    /* IE8 and older hack */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='.myBackground.jpg', sizingMethod='scale');
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='myBackground.jpg', sizingMethod='scale')";
}
```

This is a new CSS3 feature, so you have to use browser specific prefixes (`webkit`, `moz` and `o`). The solution doesn't work in IE8 and older, so you need to add the `filter` hack (see the code).

**[HERE'S](http://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/)** the full article about this method.

As the article explains, it can be unsafe to use the mentioned `filter` methods for IE due to possible scrollbar, and link issues. If you'll experience the problem you can resolve it by applying the background not to `<body>` tag but to some `<div>` which you will spread for 100% width and height. In that case you must remember to add 100% width and height also for `html` and `body`:

```css
html, body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
#bg-image {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;

    /* additional styles to let the div serve as a background, not spoiling the layout */
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;

    background: url(http://www.reactiongifs.com/r/iwsyih.gif) no-repeat center center fixed;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;

    /* IE8 and older hack */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='.myBackground.jpg', sizingMethod='scale');
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='myBackground.jpg', sizingMethod='scale')";
}
```

Example HTML:

```
<html>
    <head>
        (...)
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="bg-image"></div>

        (...)
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe that what you are trying to do is more suited to a **CSS** solution... below I have added the code that should solve your problem. Keep in mind that setting a fixed width but changing height is not the best idea as the image can become distorted. Regardless, I have included the css for setting a background image to cover your **content** container. Here is the **full** code:

```
<html> 
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0" />
        <style>
            /* # represents an id */
            #content{
                max-width: 400px; /* this is your restricted width that you are desiring */
                width: 100%; /* if you want the image to cover the whole screen regardless of the device */
                height: 100%;
                background: url(http://www.reactiongifs.com/r/iwsyih.gif) no-repeat center center fixed;
                -webkit-background-size: cover;
                -moz-background-size: cover;
                -o-background-size: cover;
                background-size: cover;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>    
        <div id="content">
            <img src="http://www.reactiongifs.com/r/iwsyih.gif" />
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            window.onload = function () {
                var elem =
                document.getElementById('content');
                window.external.Notify(elem.scrollHeight + '');
            }
        </script>
    <body>
</html>
```

As you might have noticed I added  and  tags to your code, without these your code will not behave as expected. **You should be able to copy and past this code**. Hope it helps :).